# Repeating important updates for Microsoft Office 2007

Tags: windows-vista, microsoft-office, updates, windows-update

Today I've started important updates for Windows Vista on laptop. Those updates include updates for other programs from Microsoft Update including Microsoft Office 2007 suit. All important updates were up to date of today for the Vista as well as for Office. All updates were successful today, but 3 of them KB2760823, KB2760588, KB2760411 also succeeded, but after install it searches again for updates and shows this updates again. Repeating the procedure does change nothing. Is there a legitimate way to install these updates and fix the bug in the Windows Update Center to not include those updates if they were already installed. Or may be those updates not actually installed? How to check the status in other way than looking into Windows Update Center?

I have uninstalled those updates from Windows Update Center and rebooted the system. No pending updates are installed. After reboot it shows 4 important updates. One more update is KB27605083. And I don't know what to do because this update is already installed. The only reasonable extension will be remove this update and reboot again.

Comment: I haven't had any troubles with windows update however I remember seeing something about windows update not updating everything earlier yesterday, it may just be a problem with the service.

Comment: yes, I also haven't for years till today. Updates are working and succeeds but showing again. Also I can uninstall them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Edit Fri. 13, 2013: This has be rectified by Microsoft.  See further Edit below.*

It's not just you.  This is a wide-spread problem currently affecting many people.

See: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_update/updates-trying-to-install-over-and-over-again/2a624908-f4b1-46d8-87ed-caa09674ff4f

The above thread was just started yesterday (Sept 10, 2013).

The "media" is even starting to cover it:

- http://www.pcpro.co.uk/news/enterprise/384139/office-updates-trapped-in-installation-loop
- http://news.softpedia.com/news/KB2760411-KB2760588-and-KB2760583-Windows-7-Updates-Cannot-Be-Installed-381949.shtml
- http://www.infoworld.com/t/microsoft-windows/microsoft-botches-still-more-patches-in-latest-automatic-update-226594

Blurb:

> The latest batch of security updates for Microsoft Office appears to
>   be leaving some users trapped in an installation loop.

Blurb:

> It must be Wretched Wednesday -- the day after Black Tuesday. Watch
>   out for automatic patches KB 2817630, KB 2810009, KB 2760411, KB
>   2760588, and KB 2760583

The answer (so far) seems to be "wait for MS to fix the detection problem".

---

> *Microsoft Security Bulletin Minor Revisions*
>
> Date: **Fri, 13 Sep 2013** 15:25:04 -0600,  the problems were
>   detection and have been fixed. I unhid the 3 updates that were
>   repeating on my Win 7 Pro notebook, and then ran an update checkk. 
>   Windows updates did detect the updates and no new updates were
>   detected (unless you have not yet installed the latest definitions for
>   MS Security Essentials.
>
> Here are the details of the fix  Summary  =======  The following
>   bulletins have undergone minor revision increments.   Please see the
>   bulletins for more details.
>         * MS13-063   * MS13-067   * MS13-072   * MS13-073   * MS13-074
>
> Bulletin Information:  =====================
>
> - MS13-063 - Important
>
>   - https://technet.microsoft.com/security/bulletin/ms13-063
>   - Reason for Revision: V1.2 (September 13, 2013): Corrected 
>       update replacement for all affected software excluding Windows XP 
>       and Windows 8. This is an informational change only.
>   - Originally posted: August 13, 2013
>   - Updated: September 13, 2013
>   - Bulletin Severity Rating: Important
>   - Version: 1.2
> - MS13-067 - Critical
>
>   - https://technet.microsoft.com/security/bulletin/ms13-067
>   - Reason for Revision: V1.2 (September 13, 2013): Revised 
>       bulletin to announce a detection change for the Excel Services 
>       on Microsoft SharePoint Server 2007 update (2760589). 
>       This is a detection change only. There were no changes to 
>       the update files. Customers who have successfully installed 
>       the update do not need to take any action.
>   - Originally posted: September 10, 2013
>   - Updated: September 13, 2013
>   - Bulletin Severity Rating: Critical
>   - Version: 1.2
> - MS13-072 - Important
>
>   - https://technet.microsoft.com/security/bulletin/ms13-072
>   - Reason for Revision: V1.1 (September 13, 2013): Revised 
>       bulletin to announce detection changes for the Microsoft 
>       Office 2007 update (2760411) and the Microsoft Word 2010 
>       update (2767913). These are detection changes only. There 
>       were no changes to the update files. Customers who have 
>       successfully installed the updates do not need to take 
>       any action. Also updated the Known Issues entry in the 
>       Knowledge Base Article section from "Yes" to "None".
>   - Originally posted: September 10, 2013
>   - Updated: September 13, 2013
>   - Bulletin Severity Rating: Important
>   - Version: 1.1
> - MS13-073 - Important
>
>   - https://technet.microsoft.com/security/bulletin/ms13-073
>   - Reason for Revision: V1.1 (September 13, 2013): Revised
>       bulletin to announce detection changes for the Microsoft
>       Excel 2003 update (2810048), Microsoft Excel 2007 update
>       (2760583), Microsoft Office Excel Viewer update (2760590),
>       and Microsoft Office Compatibility Pack update (2760588).
>       These are detection changes only. There were no changes
>       to the update files. Customers who have successfully
>       installed the updates do not need to take any action.
>       Also updated the Known Issues entry in the Knowledge
>       Base Article section from "Yes" to "None".
>   - Originally posted: September 10, 2013
>   - Updated: September 13, 2013
>   - Bulletin Severity Rating: Important
>   - Version: 1.1
> - MS13-074 - Important
>
>   - https://technet.microsoft.com/security/bulletin/ms13-074
>   - Reason for Revision: V1.1 (September 13, 2013): Revised 
>       bulletin to announce a detection change for the Microsoft 
>       Access 2013 (64-bit editions) update (2810009). This is a 
>       detection change only. There were no changes to the update
>       files. Customers who have successfully installed the 
>       update do not need to take any action.
>   - Originally posted: September 10, 2013
>   - Updated: September 13, 2013
>   - Bulletin Severity Rating: Important
>   - Version: 1.1

If you have previously hidden these updates you should probably un-hide them to ensure future versions of those updates get applied.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, one more thing which of them are important, because I don't use recommended updates without need or I'm sure If I need it.

Comment: I don't know.  Perhaps read their related KB articles, and then decide if you feel they are "important" enough to you. :)

Comment: I don't have first two in my installed and waiting for update lists. I have checked now what they are and they are for Office 2013 is not my case.

Comment: OMG, one guy has used to hide those updates from the list, I think I should follow it, because there no any other reasonable way to do it, or may be tricking a registry in some way, not sure about it.

Comment: The updates are actually applied the first time (check the version numbers of the modified files in the KB articles), so there is no harm in hiding the updates to prevent the continued re-offering. The KB articles have been updated to reflect that this can happen.

Answer (score 0):

Try uninstalling/re-installing them.

If that doesn't work, check that you don't have the option to turn off your computer and install updates. Should look like this:

[image]

Sometimes if there are updates pending to fully install it doesn't install more.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have just uninstalled them. I have not pending updates. I will reboot now, then update center still shows the 3 important update I need to install. I will do it after reboot.

Comment: Could you check may be I need to install a recommending update for Office 2007, before this updates. As far as I know they should not interfere.

Comment: I have updated the status, please check the question.

Answer (score 0):

Ya.  I'm having the same issue across Windows XP machines for 2007 updates.  I've successfully installed them and they keep popping up and our end users keep calling us nagging about them.  So, I've just unchecked them and checked box to never show again...problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

The only problem with unchecking them, is that when Microsoft finally does get this figured out, which should be soon, you wont recieve the notification that they need to be updated, hence leaving your computer open to security issue for those fixes. Best thing should be to just ignore them until we find out they are fixed, and then apply the update.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why this has worked but:

- I did what john hamilton suggested and unchecked the boxes, then checked the box to never show again and this stopped the updates from popping up again. I checked that the updates were still installed ( in "add or remove programs" checked "show updates" box to check they were still there) and they were.
- then got worried because of what jason said ( may not be notified of update to fix the problem) so I went to the Microsoft update website, clicked on "Express", was notified that I had "hidden" or unchecked these three updates and was asked if I wanted to reverse this and re-install, did that ("0" kb download, as the updates were already there on my computer I guess), went through the install process again, and haven't seen the "Updates..." prompt come up again.

Don't know why this worked but seems to have.